# Potentially, Probable, Partial Puzzle?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, steganography, cryptic-clues

Enjoy some fun-ish facts and a brief puzzle.

> Hundred is historically a country or shire subdivision in Britain.
>   
>  A part of U.S. history that is often unknown, is about the "Free
>   State of Van Zandt".
>  Aristotle found sounds when discovering waves
>   through air's motion.
>  It's thought that like 80% of the world's
>   gold is still underground.
>  The term for a cat hairball is called a
>   "bezoar", but it's not exclusive to cats.
>  600 BC Sybaris, Greece,
>   because noise levels were high, roosters and tinsmiths were
>   banned.
>  Each year, over 3,000,000,000 cards are shipped in the
>   U.S. for Christmas.

Comment: @humn Funnier, funner or funerish?

Comment: A few of these facts are actually fun-er than merely fun-ish. Funteresting! Carefully worded too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First the steganography:

> Taking the first word from the first fact, the second word from the second fact and so on, we get:
>
>     Hundred part sounds like cat noise shipped
>
>  This looks like a cryptic clue.

The cryptic-clues tag is next:

> The solution to the above clue is:
>
>     PERCENT (hundred part) — a homophone (sounds like) PURR (cat noise) SENT (shipped)
>
>  This solution also relates to the title: Probabilities are often given as percentages; partial means less than 100%. And there's also a percentage in the fourth fact.

What's missing?

> In chat, the poster has said that the enumeration is also hidden in the facts. Other that there are seven facts, I can't see how, though.

Comment: That would be spot on - and yes the 7 facts/7 words in the CC was supposed to tip off the enumeration. Well done :)