# Your Dream Job Awaits

Tags: steganography

A local job advertisement has caught your interest.  Sounds like the perfect place to work.

[image: T]

Comment: I am thinking that in the editing window, the images is labelled 'T'. I'm not sure if this helps, but good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***OP consolidation of other answers***

[@Marius's](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/52475/2071) found the following

> C in the copyright sign
>  missing G in 'amazin'
>  bold I
>  2 types of bullet points make P in morse code (thanks @n_palum)
>  italic C
>  reverse T
>  flipped E
>  different font A

[@AlixEisenhardt](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/52474/2071) adds

> "r" from "retirement" (different color)

[@jeyejow](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/52476/2071) contributed

> the phone number solved like a math problem is 20 (T)

[@Goodra](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52473/your-dream-job-awaits#comment160813_52473) commented

> in the editing window, the images is labelled 'T'

And there are a few that were not found

> R, faded into the background (mid-right)
>  E, the background color is #EEEEEE
>  A, text color is #0A0A0A

Which brings us to [@n_palum](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52473/your-dream-job-awaits#comment160819_52475)

> TARGET PRACTICE, which may fit the description, but is likely not your dream job

Answer (score 3):

I'm taking baby steps on my first steganography attempt. Here is what I have:

> `C` in the copyright sign.  (line 1)
>  a missing `g` in 'amazin' (1)
>  bold `I` (2)
>  Phone number converted to date `2021-12-27 05:07:36` It might not mean this but it looked like a date in `U` format.   (3)
>  The perks have 2 types of bullet points. That make `P` in morse code (thanks @n_palum)
>  italic `c`  (7)
>  reverse `t` (9)
>  flipped `e` (11)
>  different font `a` (14).

The only thing I can think of is something related to

> CGI (the first letters I mentioned above form this). So maybe my dream job is something related to CGI. I cannot think of anything else from the rest.

Comment: We talked a bit in chat about this already and we've found PRICETAG as an anagram of the letters. We're assuming the copyright C is unimportant. P from the .--. morse code. The rest are found. Not sure if it's a final solution.

Comment: The phone number is not meant to be a date, but is important.

Comment: If we include more letters found, we can get TARGET PRACTICE (Without the A/R as those haven't been found yet if they're supposed to be)

Comment: @n_palum I appreciate the help and the fact that you are trying to get me hooked in this type of puzzles, but I think it's better to write your own answer. You are way ahead of me on this. For me it has been a good exercise. I will try these in the future for sure.

Comment: I don't mind assisting with the partial answer, considering we've all been bouncing ideas around in chat. I don't have a complete answer so I see no reason for me to post repeats of what is already here. :)

Comment: @Marius If you feel weird about getting credit or something, you could always make it a community wiki answer.

Answer (score 0):

Investigations

> I found a few letters that came out of the pack
>
>  - "g" (missing) from amazing, line 1 (thanks to n_palum)
>  - "I" from "If", line 2
>  - "c" from "kitchen", line 7
>  - "r" from "retirement", line 8
>  - "t" from "face-to-face", line 9
>  - "e" from "are", line line 11
>  - "a" from "individuals", line 14
>  - "P" from dots and dashes which form morse code (thanks to Gareth)
>  - "C" from the copyright symbol ?
>
>  Taking the telephone number mathematically we find 164 * 59 - 9656 = 20. Another letter "t"?

Comment: I'd argue the missing 'g' from amazin[g] is also needed. - and Gareth in chat pointed out the morse code for P (.--.)

Comment: you can spell GET PIC with those letters. What's remaining? tracT (T from image title). Not sure what order the should be in.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to OP's new roundup and reveal bumping this to the front page, I have a few theories for the first time in months, but nothing solid.

Perhaps you are hoping to be hired as...

> A sniper!

Points to fit the ad:

> Clearly, you'll need the **target practice** to keep your skills sharp. The **simple solution** (albeit not a great one) to any problem person? Kill them. If you get a good opportunity right away, the job is **quick**: it's pretty much one and done. And I'm sure such covert ops would pay very well. You could **work from home** doing research on your target and then go jetsetting off **around the world** to locate and eliminate them. **It doesn't matter who you are** as long as you can shoot.

Along similar lines, perhaps you could be...

> THIS GUY!
>
>  [image: Sterling Archer]
>
>  ...because target practice $\rightarrow$ Archer (hah) + my points from above...

Ehhhh, I had something better but now I don't remember what it was. I don't think this is actually the answer, but thought it was worth at least throwing out there.

Answer (score -4):

So we have a missing G and the rest is mentioned by @Alix

So all together, we have "g I c r t e a "

There is nothing on imgur for this ([http://imgur.com/gIcrtea](https://imgur.com/gIcrtea))

Another thing I noticed in the perks, it goes: .--.
Maybe there's something going on involving those dots and lines.

This can mean nothing, but if we take the phone number and try to solve it like it was a math problem, the result is 20.

> (164) * 059 - 9656

EDIT: New letters added, P (from morse code) and C (copyright symbol, though I'm not too sure on this one.)

Results from imgur = none.
Link I tried:
[http://imgur.com/cgIpcrtea](https://imgur.com/cgIpcrtea)

Comment: This isn't really providing anything new. Just telling us stuff doesn't work doesn't answer the puzzle. And listing off words doesn't either.

Comment: whatever you say

Comment: Note: in the case of finding characters that point to another image, links will 99% of the time be for the SE image upload site: `https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXXXX.png` where XXXXX are the 5 characters that were hidden.